# How can I extract images from a Matlab mlarray and display them

Tags: python, arrays, image, matlab

In Python, I have an array comes from Matlab function using Matlab engine.

```
import matlab.engine
import numpy as N
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
a= eng.func()
print(type(a))
print(N.shape(a))
```

the console output is :

```
 <class 'matlab.mlarray.double'>
  (135L, 134L, 7L)
```

in which there is 7 gray images with size of 135x134.
how can I extract each image and show them by loop?

Comment: It looks like your title has _nothing_ to do with your actual question. Please fix it.

Comment: what should I name it? I have problem with dimension of output array. help me by good title. @Chris

Comment: Then maybe your question needs rewording… it looks like you really want to know "How can I extract images from a Matlab mlarray and display them?" That doesn't seem to have anything to do with array dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it according to last nice answer in
[How to efficiently convert Matlab engine arrays to numpy ndarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155829/how-to-efficiently-convert-matlab-engine-arrays-to-numpy-ndarray)

```
b = N.array(a._data).reshape(a.size, order='F')
```

it change 'a' to Numpy. and then I call each image simply.

```
for i in range(0, 6):
  c = b[:,:,i] #now c is 135x134 
  plt.imshow(c)
  plt.show()
```