# Improve performance of converting matlab arrays to numpy arrays

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I stumbled upon [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284124/improve-performance-of-converting-numpy-array-to-matlab-double).

I'm using python from matlab ([reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html)). creating numpy arrays is as easy as `py.numpy.array(rand(1, 10))`. By passing the dimensions I can also create a small method that will allow me to pass multidimensional arrays.

The performance, though, is awful. I guess it's because the conversion is first to python's list and then to matlab array (boxing and unboxing).

Is there a way (like the one suggested in the referenced question) to improve that conversion?

Comment: Something like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45290997/4045774

Comment: that's when calling matlab from inside python. I'm doing the opposite - inside matlab calling python.