# Efficiently pass numpy array to Matlab function

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am working with some python codes that call a Matlab function. The Matlab function takes a 3D array as input and the size is about 87*195*126. I modified the `mlarray_sequence.py` as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284124/improve-performance-of-converting-numpy-array-to-matlab-double/45284125#45284125). The time spent on converting to Matlab double array does significantly reduce (~0.4 sec). However, it still seems that it takes about 10 seconds to pass the array to the Matlab function, as can be seen by timing each step as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import matlab.engine
import matlab
from io import StringIO
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
import timeit

def test1():
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    matlabEngine = matlab.engine.connect_matlab()
    directory = abspath(dirname(__file__))
    matlabFolder = directory
    matlabEngine.addpath(matlabFolder)
    matlabEngine.cd(matlabFolder)

    timepoint = timeit.default_timer()
    print('Elapsed time for connecting matlab is {} sec'.format(timepoint - start_time))

    img = np.random.rand(87, 195, 126)
    timepoint1 = timeit.default_timer()
    imgMatlab = matlab.double(img)
    timepoint2 = timeit.default_timer()
    print('Elapsed time for creating matlab array is {} sec'.format(timepoint2 - timepoint1))

    out = StringIO()
    err = StringIO()
    matlabEngine.test2(imgMatlab, stdout=out, stderr=err)
    print(out.getvalue())
    print(err.getvalue())
    timepoint3 = timeit.default_timer()
    print('Elapsed time for matlab script is {} sec'.format(timepoint3 - timepoint2))

test1()
```

```matlab
function result = test2(img)

tic
result = 1;
toc
```

And the output is:

```
Elapsed time for connecting matlab is 0.0893801 sec
Elapsed time for creating matlab array is 0.40231419999999996 sec
Elapsed time is 0.000603 seconds.
Elapsed time for matlab script is 10.4323424 sec

[Done] exited with code=0 in 11.491 seconds
```

So is there any way to reduce the time spent on passing the array to matlab function?

P.S.: I have already shared the matlab session by typing `matlab.engine.shareEngine` before I run the script.

Comment: Do you already have a shared Matlab session running? I guess not, so the most time in the function is probably spend with starting the engine. It is probably a better idea to start the Matlab session outside the function, and keep the python instance open (e.g `python -i yourfile.py`)

Comment: Easy check if to add an `split_time` after initializing the Matlab engine, than you can check what is taking up the most time within the function.

Comment: @rinkert Yes, I have already shared the maltab session by typing `matlab.engine.shareEngine` before I run the script. So it should not be the startup time that's taking so long.

Comment: Can you please verify that by timing?

Comment: @rinkert Do you mean the time for connecting to matlab? I have updated the code above and you can see that it only takes 0.08 sec to connect to matlab. And the 10.43 sec is spent on the line `matlabEngine.test2(imgMatlab, stdout=out, stderr=err)`, which essentially does nothing in matlab..