# MATLAB Engine for Python is very slow

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, matlab-engine

I have a main python script and I want to call a Matlab function (spm_filter.m) on an array.

I use something like the following:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
y_filtered = np.asarray(eng.spm_filter(filter_kernel, matlab.double(data.tolist()) ,nargout=1))
```

This works fine but it is extremely slow compared to the case where I use only Matlab to do the same thing e.g. by doing:

```
y_filtered = spm_filter(filter_kernel, data)
```

Why is the matlab engine so slow? How can I make it faster?

I do not time the start of the engine. It seems that the slow down is coming due to `matlab.double(data.tolist()`. Any way to improve this part?

Comment: What is "extremely slow"? Starting MATLAB will take time, but its a one-off initialization thing

Comment: There are two conversions of data here: `matlab.double(data.tolist())` and another one here: `np.asarray(...)`. I would guess most of your slowdown happens there. Unless you include the `matlab.engine.start_matlab()` part in your timings, starting up MATLAB will certainly take time.

Comment: @Paolo starting the engine takes 1 sec but executing the command takes minutes whereas through Matlab it takes seconds

Comment: @CrisLuengo no I do not include the start of the engine. I am only talking about the execution of the command. It takes minutes whereas through Matlab it takes seconds...

Comment: It seems that the slow down is coming due to matlab.double(data.tolist(). Any way to improve this part?

Comment: @seralouk 1 sec to open MATLAB? I seriously doubt that; how did you get this measurement?

Comment: @Paolo I do not use the interface. I simply use `import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()` and this takes 1-2 secs

Comment: I've never used MATLAB in Python but it's a huge missed opportunity if it can't handle numpy arrays out of the box. Converting a numpy array to a list and then back to an array in MATLAB seems like a huge, wasteful mess.

Comment: @AndrasDeak It cannot. You need to do that otherwise it throws an error for the data type.

Comment: I've closed as duplicate of a post that I think will solve your problem. Let me know if this is not sufficient. There is also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34155829/7328782) that has a way to speed up the conversion of MATLAB to NumPy.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the first post refers to 1D arrays that are lists already. In my case I have 2D arrays and thus `matlab.double(centered_data_session.tolist())` is inevitable...

Comment: That first answer should work for any numeric NumPy array. The 3rd answer provides another solution.

Comment: Just to mention and finally close this question that only this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284125/5025009) helped in my case. Saving the data in `.mat`format and then calling the matlab function that internally loads the data is extremely fast. I am able to do my task very fast now.